# Get all URLs for resources in sub-directory in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsfilemanager, subdirectory

I am attempting to create an array of URLs for all of the resources in a sub-directory in my iOS app. I can not seem to get to the correct path, I want to be able to retrieve the URLs even if I do not know the names (i.e. I don't want to hard code the file names into the code).

Below is a screen shot of the hierarchy, I am attempting to get all the files in the 'test' folder:
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated, I have attempted to use file manager and bundle main path but to no joy so far.

This is the only code I have currently:

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let path = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "pdf", subdirectory: "Files/test")

print(path)
```

I have also tried this code but this prints all resources, I can't seem to specify a sub-directory:

```
let fm = FileManager.default
let path = Bundle.main.resourcePath!

do {
    let items = try fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: path)

    for item in items {
        print("Found \(item)")
    }
} catch {
    // failed to read directory – bad permissions, perhaps?
}
```

Based on an answer from @vadian , The folders were changed from virtual groups to real folders. Using the following code I was able to get a list of resources:

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let path = Bundle.main.resourcePath

    let enumerator:FileManager.DirectoryEnumerator = fileManager.enumerator(atPath: "\(path!)/Files/test")!
    while let element = enumerator.nextObject() as? String {
        if element.hasSuffix("pdf") || element.hasSuffix("jpg") { // checks the extension
            print(element)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code you've written so far

Comment: @AshleyMills Updated question, don't have any code really as I have tried things and deleted if I had no luck

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Consider that the yellow folders [image] are virtual **groups**, not real folders (although Xcode creates real folders in the project directory). All files in the yellow folders are moved into the `Resources` directory in the bundle when the app is built.

Real folders in the bundle are [image] in the project navigator.

Comment: Thanks for that, I actually did not know that. It has helped me build a possible answer. Will edit my question to let others know.

Answer (score 4):

You can follow the following steps to get them:

1. Create a new folder inside your project folder with the extension is **.bundle** (for example: **Images.bundle**).
2. Copy resource files into that new folder.
3. Drag that new folder into the project that opening in Xcode.
4. Retrieve the URLs by using the following code snippet:

   ```
   let urls = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: nil, subdirectory: "Images.bundle")
   ```

You can also view the guide video here: https://youtu.be/SpMaZp0ReEo

Comment: Damn, this is elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar issue today. I needed to retrieve the URL of a resource file in a bundle ignoring its path.
I wrote the following:

```
public extension Bundle {
/// Returns the file URL for the resource identified by the specified name, searching all bundle resources.
/// - Parameter resource: The name of the resource file, including the extension.
/// - Returns: The file URL for the resource file or nil if the file could not be located.
func recurseUrl(forResource resource: String) -> URL? {
    let contents = FileManager.default.allContentsOfDirectory(atPath: self.bundlePath)
    for content in contents {
        let fileNameWithPath = NSString(string: content)
        if let fileName = fileNameWithPath.pathComponents.last {
            if resource == fileName {
                return URL(fileURLWithPath: content)
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Based on this:

```
public extension FileManager {
/// Performs a deep search of the specified directory and returns the paths of any contained items.
/// - Parameter path: The path to the directory whose contents you want to enumerate.
/// - Returns: An array of String objects, each of which identifies a file or symbolic link contained in path. Returns an empty array if the directory does not exists or has no contents.
func allContentsOfDirectory(atPath path: String) -> [String] {
    var paths = [String]()
    do {
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        let contents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: path)
        
        for content in contents {
            let contentUrl = url.appendingPathComponent(content)
            if contentUrl.hasDirectoryPath {
                paths.append(contentsOf: allContentsOfDirectory(atPath: contentUrl.path))
            }
            else {
                paths.append(contentUrl.path)
            }
        }
    }
    catch {}
    return paths
}
```

}

Which achieves the goal of retrieving the URL for the first match of a given resource filename in a bundle's resources, all directories wide.
I tend to think that Swift's `func url(forResource name: String?, withExtension ext: String?) -> URL?` should behave this way in the first place.