# Cannot read file from project subfolder

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I need to read json from project subfolder

My project folder struct is looks like:
[image]

My code is:

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "default", withExtension: "json", subdirectory: "Localization"){
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let jsonData = try decoder.decode(Class.self, from: data)

            } catch {
                print("error:\(error)")
            }
        }
```

I saw another solutions on stackoverflow and also on another pages, but all of them are looks like mine, but in my case `url` is always `nil`
What is my mistake in this case?

Comment: Make sure you have added in correct  Target , and copy item if needed check box true when you drag and drop it if the case

Comment: I created Group and File from XCode menu

Comment: Did you try removing that subdirectory part ?

Comment: @humblePilgrim Yes and I got an exception, that such file does not exists in bundle

Comment: Make sure your file exists in Copy Bundle resources

Comment: Ok, and now it thinks that the file exists, but won't give you the URL to it... interesting.

Comment: @PPL That was the issue. Thanks. I have no idea why, but Xcode did not add it to Bundle resources. Thanks. You can post your answer I will accept it

Comment: are you sure you have a _subdir_ called `"Localization"`? or it is just a _group_?

Comment: Be aware that yellow folders in Xcode are virtual groups which all represent the folder `Resources`. Real (sub)folders in the bundle are blue. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50004553/get-all-urls-for-resources-in-sub-directory-in-swift/50005735#50005735

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your `default.json` file exists in `Copy Bundle Resources` in `Build Phases` of your app Target.

then you can access it using this, no need of `subdir`.

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "default", ofType: "json") {
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```